# Can any automatic citation checkers infer about the validity of the content?

Tags: citations

Can any automatic citation checkers infer about the validity of the content?

Rather than just formatting?

I.e. if one writes something like

"abc has been studied by XYZ (2015, p. 25). In this study they made an observation about abc with 45% accuracy.".

Then the checker would check, whether the source XYZ actually talks about abc and whether at p. 25 of the linked document there is mention of this 45% accuracy thing.

Comment: Is there some reason you think such a thing might exist?

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist Because it's useful for large citation counts?

Comment: I think it's called a 'grad student'.

Comment: If you are you talking about a software that would search the Internet and make inferences, than that's technically next to impossible. But perhaps you meant something like: you have all (or most of) your references in the same folder in the same format, and you want the software to perform a local search? Even that, though, would be an immense technical challenge to perform entirely automatically, as it's hard for a computer to extract meaning from a free-form English sentence. If such a thing exists, the best it could do is to show you the page so that you can check visually.

Answer (score 7):

No, there is no such automatic citation checker. It would exceed what is technically possible at present.

Comment: Addendum: it would be a good research project for a PhD or even beyond that. There are now extractor solutions for medical and law papers. I do not know how good/reliable they are.